# Building complete JSON in grails

Tags: json, web-services, grails

My controller looks like this:

```
  def save() {
    js {
       def color = new Color(params)
       color.save()
       def result
       if (!color.hasErrors()) 
       {
          result = [colorname: color.name, colorshde: color.shade]
       }
       else
       {
         result = "..."
       }
       render result as JSON
    }

 }
```

The JSON that I desire should look like this:

Successful JSON

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": {
      "color": {
         "colorname": "Red",
         "shade": "light
      }
   }
}
```

Unsuccessful response:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 400,
      "msg": "Something went worn"
   },
   "response": {
      "color": {
      }
   }
}
```

**Question**

How can I modify the controller action to account for both scenarios while returning json?

Comment: Hey @Anthony, I saw your latest question which you deleted. I was about to say, there is a better way to create JSON response. If you want I can post it here as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For successful response:

```
{
"meta": {
  "status": 200,
  "msg": "OK"
},
"response": {
  "color": {
     "colorname": "Red",
     "shade": "light
  }
}
}
```

Use:

```
result = [meta: [status: '200', msg: 'OK'], response:[color:[colorname: color.name, colorshde: color.shade] ] ]
```

For unsuccessful response:

```
{
  "meta": {
  "status": 400,
  "msg": "Something went worn"
},
"response": {
  "color": {
  }
}
}
```

Use

```
 result = [meta: [status: '400', msg: 'wrong'], response:[color:[] ] ]
```